# How can I express the type of 'takeWhile for vectors'?

Tags: haskell, types, binding, dependent-type

Haskell beginner here. I've defined the following types:

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat
data Vector a n where
    Nil :: Vector a Z
    (:-) :: a -> Vector a n -> Vector a (S n)
infixl 5 :-
```

I'm trying to write the function, takeWhileVector which behaves the same as takeWhile does on lists, but on Vectors.

My implementation is as follows:

```
takeWhileVector :: (a -> Bool) -> Vector a n -> Vector a m
takeWhileVector f Nil = Nil
takeWhileVector f (x :- xs) = if (f x) then (x :- takeWhileVector f xs) else Nil
```

This doesn't compile and produces the following error:

```
Could not deduce (m ~ 'S n0)
from the context (n ~ 'S n1)
  bound by a pattern with constructor
             :- :: forall a (n :: Nat). a -> Vector a n -> Vector a ('S n),
           in an equation for ‘takeWhileVector’
  at takeWhileVector.hs:69:20-26
  ‘m’ is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for
        takeWhileVector :: (a -> Bool) -> Vector a n -> Vector a m
      at takeWhileVector.hs:67:20
Expected type: Vector a m
  Actual type: Vector a ('S n0)
Relevant bindings include
  takeWhileVector :: (a -> Bool) -> Vector a n -> Vector a m
    (bound at takeWhileVector.hs:69:1)
In the expression: (x :- takeWhileVector f xs)
In an equation for ‘takeWhileVector’:
    takeWhileVector f (x :- xs) = (x :- takeWhileVector f xs)
```

I would have thought that my type definition for takeWhileVector says the following:

For all types 'a' and 'n's of kind Nat, this function returns a 'Vector a m', where 'm' is kind Nat.

Do I need to change the type signature of takeWhileVector to be more specific so that it shows that the result is Vector a (m :: Nat)?
Otherwise, how can I change this to have it compile?

Comment: I've edited the title of your question to something I feel is more descriptive of what you're trying to do. If you're unhappy with my changes, you can always [edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30961556/edit) to change it back ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The type you suggest can not be implemented, i.e. it is not inhabited:

```
takeWhileVector :: (a -> Bool) -> Vector a n -> Vector a m
```

Remember that the caller chooses the type variables `a,n,m`. This means that the caller can use your function as e.g.

```
takeWhileVector :: (a -> Bool) -> Vector a Z -> Vector a (S Z)
```

which is nonsense, since you can't produce some `a`s if you got none at the beginning. Even more practically, the caller of this function is not meant to be able to choose how many results to have and pass a completely unrelated function -- that would disagree with the intended semantics of `takeWhile`.

I guess what you really mean is something like

```
takeWhileVector :: (a -> Bool) -> Vector a n -> exists m. Vector a m
```

except that `exists` is not valid Haskell syntax. Instead, you need something like

```
data SomeVector a where
   S :: Vector a m -> SomeVector a

takeWhileVector :: (a -> Bool) -> Vector a n -> SomeVector a
```

Comment: Hi Chi - thanks for the response and insight. I had considered that problem where the definition suggested the result vector could be longer than the input vector (which makes no sense as you say), however I didn't know how to encode it into the type signature. Is this 'wrapping' up of the type a common pattern to encode restrictions like this? If so, do you know what it's called so that I can read up on it?

Comment: @CodeMonkey The issue here is that you want some vector type where the length information is statically known, and another one where the length is statically unknown. You can look up "existential types" in Haskell to see the solution I suggested above. Keep also in mind that existential types are often abused, i.e. sometimes they are used instead of more plain and simpler solutions -- so use some judgment before using them everywhere.

Comment: @CodeMonkey Further, in dependently typed languages, you can be even more precise, stating something like `(exists m . m <= n && Vector a m)` which ensures that the result is shorted than the input list. Encoding this is Haskell is probably doable, but requires a lot of type-level expertise, and depending on the application at hand, may not be worth the effort.

Comment: Hi, thanks again, this makes sense - I'll check out the existential types. :-)

Comment: The completely parametric signature would still make some sense if the result were `Maybe (Vector a m)`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: With some hard work you could probably make that version of `takeWhile` compile, but it would be difficult to call it. The calling context would have to statically predict the length of the output vector. Dependent pairs which return a witness to the static property are the canonical way of typing such functions.

Answer (score 7):

There's no way to statically know the length of the `Vec` that is returned by `takeWhileVec`: it depends on the values contained in the `Vec`, and the function you use. However, what I can do is give you a value which you can pattern-match on to *learn* the length of the `Vec`. Enter [*singleton values*](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~eir/papers/2012/singletons/paper.pdf).

```
data Natty n where
    Zy :: Natty Z  -- pronounced 'zeddy', because I'm a limey
    Sy :: Natty n -> Natty (S n)  -- pronounced 'essy'
```

For a given `n` of kind `Nat`, there is exactly one (non-`undefined`) value of type `Natty n`. So if you know something about a `Natty`, you also know something about its associated type-level `Nat`.*

Why can't we just use `Nat` for this purpose? Haskell maintains a separation between values and types. The type-level `Nat` has no relation, other than a structural similarity, to the value-level `Nat`: the value `S Z` has a type of `Nat`, not `S' Z'` - so we have to use `Natty`, a second copy of `Nat`, to manually tie values and types together. (Real dependently-typed systems such as Agda allow you to reuse the same `Nat` for both value-level and type-level computations.)

<sub>*You can propagate knowledge the other way too, using type classes.</sub>

---

The plan is to return the output vector as well as its length as a `Natty`, with the types arranged in such a way that GHC understands that the `Natty` does indeed represent its length. You might first consider this variation on the example in your question:

```
-- takeWhile :: (a -> Bool) -> Vec a n -> (Natty m, Vec a m)
```

But this doesn't say the right thing: we're saying `takeWhile` can return any `m` of the caller's choice, which isn't true! It can only return the unique `m` determined by the function and the input vector. As I mentioned, this is un-knowable at compile-time, so we have to keep the length a secret from the compiler.

```
data AVec a = forall n. AVec (Natty n) (Vec a n)
```

`AVec` is an [existential type](https://wiki.haskell.org/Existential_type): `n` appears on the right-hand side but not the left. This technique allows you to emulate a [*dependent pair type*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type#Dependent_pair_type): the type of the `Vec` depends on the value of the `Natty`. Dependent pairs are useful whenever the static properties of data depend on dynamic information not available at compile-time.

We can write `takeWhile` straightforwardly now:

```
takeWhile :: (a -> Bool) -> Vec a n -> AVec a
takeWhile f Nil = AVec Zy Nil
takeWhile f (x :- xs) = case takeWhile f xs of
                             AVec n ys -> if f x
                                          then AVec (Sy n) (x :- ys)
                                          else AVec Zy Nil
```

We had to throw away static knowledge of the Vector's length, so how do you use an `AVec` with a function which places static requirements on the length? Because of the way `AVec` is constructed, we know that the `Natty` in the left slot represents the length of the vector in the right slot: they both feature the same (existentially hidden) type parameter `n`. So, by pattern-matching on the `Natty`, we learn the length of the `Vec`.

```
head :: Vec a (S n) -> a
head (x :- xs) = x

head' :: AVec a -> Maybe a
head' (AVec Zy Nil) = Nothing
head' (AVec (Sy n) xs) = Just (head xs)
```

In this example, we only care whether the vector is longer than one, so pattern matching on `Sy` is enough to prove to GHC that we should be allowed to use `head`. (See [a related answer of mine](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/276916/103810) for a more involved example of proving facts about `AVec`s.)

---

@chi mentioned a tantalising idea: you might want to show that the vector returned by `takeWhile` is not longer than the input vector.

```
takeWhile :: (a -> Bool) -> Vec a n -> AShorterVec a n
```

where `AShorterVec` is the type of vectors no longer than `n`. Our challenge is to write down the definition of `AShorterVec`.

Given two natural numbers, how can you be sure that the first is less-than-or-equal to the second? The relation is inductive. If the left operand is zero, then it's less-than-or-equal to any natural number automatically. Otherwise, a number is less-than-or-equal to another if its predecessor is less-than-or-equal to the other's predecessor. We can encode that as a constructive proof using a GADT.

```
data LTE n m where
    ZLte :: LTE Z m
    SLte :: LTE n m -> LTE (S n) (S m)
```

If `n` is less than `m`, you'll be able to come up with a value of `LTE n m`. If it's not, you can't. This is what the [Curry-Howard isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence) is all about.

Now we're ready to define `AShorterVec`: in order to construct a value of `AShorterVec a n` you need to be able to prove that it's shorter than `n` by supplying a value of `LTE m n`. When you pattern-match on the `AShorterVec` constructor, it gives you the proof back so you can compute with it.

```
data AShorterVec a n = forall m. AShorterVec (LTE m n) (Vec a m)
```

`takeWhile` compiles with only a minor change: we have to manipulate this proof object.

```
takeWhile :: (a -> Bool) -> Vec a n -> AShorterVec a n
takeWhile f Nil = AShorterVec ZLte Nil
takeWhile f (x :- xs) = case takeWhile f xs of
                             AShorterVec prf ys -> if f x
                                                   then AShorterVec (SLte prf) (x :- ys)
                                                   else AShorterVec ZLte Nil
```

---

An alternative way to give a type to `takeWhile` is to push the upper bound on the length into the return type itself, rather than carrying it around as data. This approach dispenses with any wranglings with `Natty`, proof terms like `LTE`, and existential quantifications.

```
data ShorterVec a n where
    SNil :: ShorterVec a n
    SCons :: a -> ShorterVec a n -> ShorterVec a (S n)
```

Once again, `ShorterVec a n` denotes the set of vectors no longer than `n`. The structure of `ShorterVec` is reminiscent of the [finite sets](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-fin-0.1.0/docs/Data-Number-Fin-Integer.html), but translated from the world of naturals into the world of vectors. An empty vector is shorter than any length you care to name; a cons cell increases the smallest valid upper bound by one. Note that the value of `n` is never fully determined by a value of type `ShorterVec`, so you can give any valid upper bound to a `ShorterVec`. These two expressions are both well-typed:

```
ok1 = SCons 1 (SCons 3 SNil) :: ShorterVec Int (S (S (S Z)))
ok2 = SCons 1 (SCons 3 SNil) :: ShorterVec Int (S (S Z))
```

but this one is not:

```
-- notOk = SCons 1 (SCons 3 SNil) :: ShorterVec Int (S Z)  -- the vector is longer than our stated upper bound.
```

Using this datatype, you can write a beautifully simple version of `takeWhile` which looks exactly like the original list version:

```
takeWhile :: (a -> Bool) -> Vec a n -> ShorterVec a n
takeWhile f Nil = SNil
takeWhile f (x :- xs) = if f x
                        then SCons x (takeWhile f xs)
                        else SNil
```

Relaxing our assumptions about the type has made the function simpler to implement, but you pay the cost of having another type which you need to convert to and from. You can translate from `ShorterVec` back into the version which used a dependent pair by measuring the length.

```
toAVec :: ShorterVec a n -> AVec a
toAVec SNil = AVec Zy Nil
toAVec (SCons x xs) = case toAVec xs of
                           AVec n ys -> AVec (Sy n) (x :- ys)
```

---

We started out using singletons to tie types and values together, and existential types to wrap up runtime information about data with the data itself. Then, following @chi's idea, we encoded (one part of) the *correctness* of `takeWhile` into the type signature using a proof-term. Then we came up with a way to bake the length invariant into the return type directly, dispensing with the need to prove any theorems.

Once you've got the taste of dependently-typed programming on your tongue, it's hard to go back to the old way. Expressive type systems give you at least three advantages: you can write valid programs which other languages would disallow (or force you to duplicate code); you can write more meaningful types for the same functions, making stronger promises; and you can prove the correctness of your programs in a machine-checkable way.

Haskell's not set up for it, though. One problem is that singletons make binding types and values needlessly complex: the `Nat`-`Natty` distinction causes an explosion of boilerplate code, most of which I've spared you, to shuffle between the types and values. (Much of this boilerplate can be automated - that's what [the `singletons` library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons) gives you.) If we wanted to specify another aspect of the correctness of `takeWhile` - the fact that all of the output list's elements satisfy the predicate - we'd have to work exclusively with lists of singletons and type-level predicate functions. I also find it tedious to declare a new top-level type every time I want to quantify something existentially (you can write libraries to help with this, though they often result in other boilerplate) - we have the lack of type-level lambdas to thank for that. The other main difficulty is restrictions in what can be promoted to the type-level using `DataKinds`: GADTs and existential types can't be promoted, so for example you can't have a multi-dimensional array whose shape is expressed statically as a `Vec Nat n`.
No real dependently typed system makes dependent types this difficult to use!

Comment: Minor glitch in `lteSucc`: `ZL,SL,slt` are the wrong names, I think.

Comment: Well spotted, copy and paste fail on my part! I'll fix it ;)